# Why are my console.logs not being written?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, console, google-chrome-devtools

I'm in the middle of refactoring an asp.net report that uses MVC. I  removed some of the criteria for the report (no longer wanted) and added some new criteria, but now the report isn't being generated at all. I click the submit button, and it simply returns.

So, I added some console.log statements to the code as a sanity check that I was at least getting there:

```
   $("#submit_button").click(function () {
        console.log("submit btn clicked");

        $("#NumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#NumberOfResults").html("Please wait...");

        EnableButton("submit_button", false);

        var deptsList = $('#depts').checkedBoxes();
        $('#deptHeader span').html(deptsList.join(", "));
        var sitesList = $('#sites').checkedBoxes();
        $('#sitesHeader span').html(sitesList.join(", "));

        $('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList); //do I need to make this: $('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList).join(","); ?
        $('#hiddenSites').val(sitesList); // ""
        var UPCs = $('UPC').val();
        if (UPCs == "All") {
            $('UPC').val("1"); // take everything (1 and greater)
        }

        console.log("about to submit the form");
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

I thought maybe that it was failing because not all the values to be passed were valid (modelState contained errors), but wouldn't that objection to further processing come *after* the call to $("form").submit(); ?

IOW, I would expect to see "submit btn clicked" and "about to submit the form" in the console after mashing the submit button and then F12, but I don't...

It is true that three of the five model members are empty strings, so I have more problems to track down, but why am I not even seeing these console log messages?

### UPDATE

I have a breakpoint in the Controller on the last line here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria(TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel model)
{
     ViewBag.DebugMessage = "No error";  
     if (ModelState.IsValid) // inspect locals.modelstate [breakpoint set here]
```

...but I don't even reach it...?!?!?

### UPDATE 2

In answer to Karl Anderson, here's the relevant HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="bottomButtonEnabled">View Report</button>
```

### UPDATE 3

If there's a way to get the console messages as text, I couldn't see how, so I captured a scream shot:

[image]

If your eyes are too small to read it, so to speak (mine are), here's some of the verbiage:

shouldShowTB file Not Exist - default action show Toolbar > DOMException
chrom.tabs is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. ensure that....
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  ...sprite.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Failed to load resource         chrome-extension://klibjjljfadl;fjkdlfjkdl;;fjdlfjadl/tb/al/state.html
MessagingReadyWrapper did not get ready. name: abstractionLayerBack.js , location ....
Time out waiting for a plugin, calling ready without a plugin
...

### UPDATE 4

I did what Aegis said, and with either the submit button itself or with:

```
form action="/mypath/mycshtml" method="post"
```

...highlighted in CDT after right-clicking and selecting "Inspect Element", I see at the bottom of the right pane:

submit
    form
...and then a bunch of "gobbledygook" (it's g[r]eek to me; maybe Aegis understands it)

The referenced file is jquery.js:6497; Below that it shows a bunch of stuff for the jquery (sourcename's value is the path to google's CDN jQuery file). Should it be pointing to my submit_button click handler instead?

### UPDATE 5

Maybe at least part of my problem was that I was calling "form".submit explicitly, which shouldn't be necessary with a submit button - mashing it should automatically submit the form, right? After commenting that out (after experimenting with the raw javascript of document.form.submit()) I at least now see the first console.log msg I added ("submit btn clicked") in the console. So somewhere between there and the second console.log msg (which is not being written to the console) something is failing.

Comment: Is your jQuery selector right? Is it a button with `ID` of `submit_button`? Or is it a class of `submit_button`? Or is `submit_button` the wrong value all together?

Comment: First check you console for any potential syntax errors, which might prevent the code form running in the first place

Comment: @Karl Anderson: See Update 2.

Comment: @Sushanth (wasn't that the name of a castle in Persia?): Please see Update 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making it all the way through the submit function now. It seems two things were causing my problem:

0) The superfluous call to submit the form when it already was going to be submitted by default because this was a submit input widget
1) A call to .join here:

```
$('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList).join(",");
```

Once I chopped off the join:

```
$('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList);
```

...I made it past that spot.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the Chrome dev tools if the event is bound to `#submit_button`?

Comment: Do you mean to see if it really is considered to be bound, from Chrome's perspective? If I knew how, I would...

Comment: Right Click -> Inspect Element. In the sidebar on the right where you can see the CSS rules associated to the selected element, scroll to the bottom and open "Event Listeners" then "click". Check for the presence of your function.